# Unavailable This video can't be embedded. facebook fix

Tags: facebook, video, embed

Cannot get this video to embed. It worked when it was live, but now after it's not working.

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/?prefill_href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FNortheasternCAMD%2Fvideos%2F244765403426776%2F&**cft**[0]=AZWPigSAACUzu30DNIabhiTulSmLfcfRPCq71EI3eVZfDLid1EXDxvbeRXdX84YuUPT7R8J_4qppETE_0UeynBNs8Phg3q6t3blpV1QwuUeCMb99emMNVHwzYhbjt5OUOZ4c6HOi1CmXJ8-Knnuv-tDqTtTThPNOz0S6Sygdc7k6JMh-UhFWOlEhzCZ6_o5h25o&**tn**=p%2CP-R#code-generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/?prefill_href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FNortheasternCAMD%2Fvideos%2F244765403426776%2F&__cft__[0]=AZWPigSAACUzu30DNIabhiTulSmLfcfRPCq71EI3eVZfDLid1EXDxvbeRXdX84YuUPT7R8J_4qppETE_0UeynBNs8Phg3q6t3blpV1QwuUeCMb99emMNVHwzYhbjt5OUOZ4c6HOi1CmXJ8-Knnuv-tDqTtTThPNOz0S6Sygdc7k6JMh-UhFWOlEhzCZ6_o5h25o&__tn__=p%2CP-R#code-generator)

It's a public video.

Comment: Please be more specific. How are you trying to embed this video? Which technologies are you using?

Comment: @ionpoint I am trying to embed this video just via iframe: https://www.facebook.com/NortheasternCAMD/videos/244765403426776/

Comment: Public does not automatically mean embedable. The video owner could have changed the settings, specifically so as to _not_ make it embedable any more.

Comment: Oh that's interesting... I am the owner of the video and I cannot find any settings in order to change that.

Comment: It seems Facebook live replays cannot be embedded. I searched through a lot of forums and the same problem occurred. I resorted to uploading the content on YouTube.

Comment: Unfortunately its a said truth. It's a trust issue with Facebook and the users of embedded videos....yet the facebook page plugin allows it. So odd...